# Align two Flex box dynamically using Angular

Tags: html, angular, css, flexbox

In my web-app I implemented flexbox using Angular framework. The funtionaly of this flex box is at first the first one will show on the window. When user will click one specific item from that flexbox, another flex box will appear. The first flex box will appear the entire window of the app. When another will appear the first one will automatically strech to 50% of the entire window. But I am very new in Angular. At this moment I set width of company-list to 50% and company-detail to auto. The first flexbox is streched but when resizing the window the two flex box are not in equal size. I would lie to show the company-list with the entire window at first. and also like to strech it when another flex (company detail) will be apperaed. But how can I achieve this.

My Code is

CSS

```
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
}


.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

HTML code

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fx-offset=15>
<h2 class="dtable-h2">{{ 'A926Companies' | translate }}</h2>
</div>
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch">
    <div class="company-list" style="margin-top:10px;">

        <!-- create company button -->

    </div>

    <div class="company-detail" style="margin-top:10px;">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really related to Angular but anyway.

Here is how.

```js
function addBox() {
  const container = document.querySelector('.container');
  const box = document.createElement('div');
  container.appendChild(box);
}
```

```css
.container {
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 12px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.container div {
  background: teal;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  margin: 0 6px;
  padding: 12px;
}

button {
  padding: 12px 24px;
  background: orange;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <button onclick="addBox()">Add box</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

### EDIT

In the case of using **Flex Layout** :

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch">
  <div class="company-list" style="margin-top:10px;" fxFlex> </div>
  <div class="company-detail" style="margin-top:10px;" fxFlex="50%"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in my case how can I resize the two flex box. Shall I need any angular code for that?

Comment: I have edited my answer, see under the snippet for Angular.

Comment: Hi, i have tried your answer but the same result appear, the first flexbox stands at the left side of the window and the second is the right. But I want to set company-list in the entire window at first, then it willshrink to 50% when new company detail will apear

Comment: Just as your sample code. But I do not not know how can I do that in angular?

Comment: Then remove the first `50%`. I edited my answer if you want to look at it.

Comment: I remove the the first 50%. But it is in the middle. I want to show the entire window. iT is not streching, It just move to the left when new flexbox come :(

Comment: `center stretch` should be `start stretch`, but if the div doesn't take the whole space with only `fxFlex`, then you have an issue with your CSS. Could you make a [mcve] on stackblitz ?

Comment: As you can see **[here on this sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qtpsg5?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)** it works like a charm

Comment: how can I do Minimal, complete and verification example. I gave the CSS which I am using in my code. Shall I give more on the HTML?

Comment: Look at my previous comment, and use the same website. It's a sandbox where you can put your code, and I can play with it. Since it works for me, I need to see why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Hi I tried to generate code but nothing happens could you plaese have a look in my source code, which I gave. I really got puzzled now

Comment: No I can't. I need a sandbox. I gave you one, if you can't provide one, then look at mine and adapt it to your case. I told you, there's an issue with your css, unless I see it in live action, I can't figure out what is the issue.